# How to extract an information from... what I would call an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

There's this awful website that put up interesting videos from YouTube. The problem is I hate the way they replace the youtube controlls for those horrible Fash player thinggy. So I went into their code in order to find the place they hide the YouTube link... its right there in a JavaScript/jQuery thing (at the end):

```
if (typeof (jQuery) == "function") {
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.fitVids = function () {}
    })(jQuery)
};
jwplayer('jwplayer-0').setup({
    "aspectratio": "16:9",
    "width": "100%",
    "primary": "flash",
    "skin": "vapor",
    "advertising": {
        "client": "vast",
        "tag": "http://d.adgear.com/impressions/int_nc/as=9976191.xml"
    },
    "ga": {},
    "sharing": {},
    "image": "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/hHbAEl1Wbms/0.jpg",
    "file": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHbAEl1Wbms"
});
```

And so the only thing I'm looking for is a way to extract the the "file" information (containing the youtube link) into a variable, so that I can inject a simple :

```
var a = "file"; //(<-- this is the thing I need)    
window.onload=function(){ window.location.href = a; }
```

as soon as the page load.

Edit*
I might have badly explained what I wanted, but I feel like were geting there so I'll try to clarify. There's this "object"called jwplayer("jwplayer-0') followed by .setup({ containing all sorts of "attributes". That is on the page itself, now what I want to do is only to go grab the atribute called "file" containing in this case the youtube URL, witch is contained in .setup. I want to be able put the YouTube URL inside a variable and use it elswere on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your problem is that you want to replace the url and want to get the component info. You can try the below:

To change the url :

```
$("[file*='www.youtube.com']").attr("file","yourUrl");
```

To get the component info:

```
var comp = $("[file*='www.youtube.com']")
```

Comment: Samuel@Did you try the snippet above?

Comment: Yes I simply try the second one (var comp = $("[file*='www.youtube.com']")) followed with an alert(comp) and I onlny get [object Object] in the popup box

Comment: What I want the popup box to say on the page of my example is:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHbAEl1Wbms"
(with or without the quotation mark) tough, the actual url will change from one apge to another, it will always be stored in the "file" attribute

Comment: try $("[file*='www.youtube.com']").attr("file")

Comment: alert says "undefined" this time

Comment: Basically it will find the object which have file attribute containing string "youtube.com" and return its full value for the same attribute (by calling attr("file").

Comment: but the thing is .attr only gives attributes of hml elements aren they? i want the attributes of jwplayer. The URL is only acessable as texte on the wibsite inside the javascript of the page... let me jsut give you the adress, (warning, the website is  in french and its ugly as hell, and yes the example is a video of a kitten, but that's not the point...so here's the website: http://www.ayoye.co/un-chaton-dort-dans-un-verre-top-cute/

Comment: So I try to use the chrome plug in called javascript injector to redirect me directly to the youtube page of the video shared by the page. how?

Comment: I am sorry , I was referring simple JQuery earlier. This is more on plug in site which you are using.For getting the current file  use : ' jwplayer().config.file' and for changing url : 'jwplayer().load([{file:"url"}])', it should work.

Comment: Ok so here's exactly what I've input into the javascript injector for the page:

var videourllink = jwplayer().config.file();

alert(videourllink);

and nothing happen, and when i chek in the console i get:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined

Comment: Have you added the JWPlayer reference?

Comment: I have no idea what that is. You understood that its not my website or my plug-in right? You got that all I want to do is to get the straight up script that will select what the "file" : "contains"? Nothing els. I'm not trying to use the video plug-in, or trying to do anything els than to be able to handle into a variable the file thinggy.

Comment: Look now I've got this:

$(function(){
   var plainText = $('.post-single-content.box.mark-links script').text();
   alert(plainText);
});

With that I'll only have to use the regular expressions to get to select the url. So this will be fine I guess.